# JQuery how to bind on click event to all check box

Tags: jquery

I have multiple checkbox like so

```
<input name="1[]" type="checkbox">
<input name="1[]" type="checkbox">
<input name="2[]" type="checkbox">
<input name="2[]" type="checkbox">
<input name="3[]" type="checkbox">
<input name="4[]" type="checkbox">
```

How would I bind an onclick even to all of those checkbox.
And run a function.. lets say a prompt "you click one of the listed checkbox"

```
 $("input").click() {

            return confirm("you click one of the listed checkbox?");

    });
```

This doesn't work

Answer (score 5):

You need to make it a function of click

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function() {
    alert("you click one of the listed checkbox?");
});
```

Fiddled: http://jsfiddle.net/XQDfP/

Comment: If the input is type=text, this will fire as soon as you click inside the textbox.

Comment: My point exactly... it would alert the user that they clicked a checkbox when it is not a checkbox.

Comment: @Jangui no, `$('input').click(){}` is not the same as `$('input').click(function(){})`

Comment: Hey guys I just realized it's only sending the one input that i check. I actually want to send all the input in the dom.

Answer (score 1):

Use  `.change()` for checkboxes, radiobuttons etc..

```
$("input[type=checkbox]").change(function() {
        return confirm("you click one of the listed checkbox?");
});
```

However your error was that you missed to make it a function of click

```
$("input[type=checkbox]").click(function() {
        return confirm("you click one of the listed checkbox?");
});
```

Comment: Why `.change()`? `.click()` would be valid.

Comment: .click() is actually better, because there was a bug in older versions of WebKit that didn't recognize the change event on radio buttons.